# Use Default Value checkbox for custom category ui_component

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, category-attribute

I added a custom category attribute "Listing Image" and want to display the checkbox "Set Default Value", like "Thumbnail" and "Category Image". I already compared the ui_component, but couldn't find the entry for that.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="content">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Content</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="listingimage">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Listing Image</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">45</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="categorylandingpage/category/upload/attribute_code/listingimage"/>
                    </item>
                    <item name="scopeLabel" xsi:type="string">[WEBSITE]</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: See the answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/322606/2207.

Answer (score 0):

I already did that as listing grid product, see the image above.

[image]

Using:

```
  \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo,

  $this->assetRepo->getUrl('Magento_Catalog::images/product/placeholder/thumbnail.jpg');
```

**1- file Thumbnail.php**

```
  <?php

  namespace PHPAISS\Jobs\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Jobs;

  use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
  use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository;
  use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
  use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
  use PHPAISS\Jobs\Helper\Data;

class Thumbnail extends Column
{
     /**
 * Column name in job listing grid
 */
const NAME = 'thumbnail';

/**
 * Alt image
 */
const ALT_FIELD = 'title';

/**
 * @var UrlInterface
 */
private $urlBuilder;
/**
 * @var Data
 */
private $helper;
/**
 * @var Repository
 */
private $assetRepo;

/**
 * Thumbnail constructor.
 *
 * @param ContextInterface                         $context
 * @param UiComponentFactory                       $uiComponentFactory
 * @param UrlInterface                             $urlBuilder
 * @param Repository $assetRepo
 * @param Data                                     $helper
 * @param array                                    $components
 * @param array                                    $data
 */
public function __construct(
    ContextInterface $context,
    UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
    UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo,
    Data $helper,
    array $components = [],
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    $this->helper = $helper;
    $this->assetRepo = $assetRepo;
}

/**
 * Prepare Data Source
 *
 * @param array $dataSource
 * @return array
 */
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        $fieldName = self::NAME;

        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
            /** @var \PHPAISS\Jobs\Model\Job $job */
            $job = new DataObject($item);

            // Set default thumbnail as thumbnail in product listing grid
            $urlImage = $job->getImage() ?
                        $this->helper->getUrlJobImage($job->getImage()) :
                        $this->assetRepo->getUrl('Magento_Catalog::images/product/placeholder/thumbnail.jpg');

            $item[$fieldName . '_src'] = $urlImage;
            $item[$fieldName . '_alt'] = $this->getAlt($item) ?: '';
            $item[$fieldName . '_link'] = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                'jobs/job/edit',
                ['id' => $job->getEntityId(), 'store' => $this->context->getRequestParam('store')]
            );
            $item[$fieldName . '_orig_src'] = $urlImage;
        }
    }

    return parent::prepareDataSource($dataSource);
}

/**
 * @param array $row
 *
 * @return null|string
 */
protected function getAlt($row)
{
    $altField = $this->getData('config/altField') ?: self::ALT_FIELD;
    return isset($row[$altField]) ? $row[$altField] : null;
}
}
```

**2 - file jobs_job_listing.xml**

```
     <!--
     ** Thumbnail Column
     ** The name 'thumbnail' defined in const NAME = 'thumbnail' in file:
     ** \PHPAISS\Jobs\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Jobs\Thumbnail
     -->
    <column name="thumbnail" class="PHPAISS\Jobs\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Jobs\Thumbnail" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/thumbnail">
        <settings>
            <altField>title</altField>
            <hasPreview>1</hasPreview>
            <label translate="true">Thumbnail</label>
            <sortable>false</sortable>
        </settings>
    </column>
```

You can check the module in my **github**: [Jobs Module](https://github.com/aissyass/magento-jobs)